# python numpy : roll column wise with different values

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function that does the following?

Given a matrix

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
0 0 0
```

And a 1-D array of "shifting values"

```
0 1 2
```

The function would shift all the values, column wise, where each shift per column is specified by `shifting_values` ?

For example

```
> np.f(X, shifting_values,axis=1)
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

Does such a function exist? If not, is it possible to do this without using a for loop?

Comment: You should be able to adapt the answers without problems. For the first one for instance just change `r[r < 0] += A.shape[0]` and transpose the result instead to adapt it to rolling along axis 1

Comment: that worked. thanks, posting the modified version in case it's hard to work it out

Comment: ```import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]])

r = np.array([2, 0, -1])

rows, cols = np.ogrid[:A.shape[0], :A.shape[1]]

# Changes here
r[r < 0] += A.shape[0]

# Changes here
rows = rows - r[np.newaxis, :]

# Changes here
result = A[rows, cols]
```

Comment: is there an easy way to adapt this to tensors? i'm trying to shift every matrix inside a tensor by a certain amount column wise